# My query doesn't work when I add a sum() to it?

Tags: php, sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get a query to show results using php, gae and bigquery. The query happily runs and shows the correct data in my application if I do a generic select * from table, so I know everything else is fine with my code. However, as soon as I try to include a sum() in the query, my data no longer loads when I deploy the app. I'm not sure what I'm missing here, the column is a numeric data type if that helps. I've played with all parts and it seems as soon as I add sum() in, all data vanishes from my application.

```
...    
<?php
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Bigquery::BIGQUERY);
        $bigquery = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);
        $projectId = 'projectName';
        $query1 = 'SELECT column_1, SUM(column_2) as `trade_price` from [dataset.tableName] group by column_1 order by trade_price desc limit 10';
        $request = new Google_Service_Bigquery_QueryRequest();
        $str = '';
        
        $request->setQuery($query1);
        
        $response = $bigquery->jobs->query($projectId, $request);
        $rows = $response->getRows();
...
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me out!

EDIT: I need the query to be sorted from largest sum to smallest. I've tested doing sum on column_1  which is an int, and that's fine. So I'm starting to think my issue is to do with the fact column_2 is numeric, however the query I have works correctly in console, so maybe PHP and sum(numeric column) don't play nice together? How would I resolve this?

Comment: The query is logically correct.  Is there any sort of error message?

Comment: No, my application loads, it just loads without the data (e.g. I still get my header and all other info on the page, just my table is not there, I presume as it is empty?). 
I'm confused because when I run everything the same with the only change being SELECT column_1 from [dataset.tableName] desc limit 10, it is fine?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that some older versions of SQL don't like you ordering by an alias name that is assigned in the same query eg `trade_price` is assigned as the alias name for `sum(column_2)`. I'm grasping at straws here but you could try `order by 2 desc` where `2` represents the 2nd column.

Comment: Hi @JohnD, thanks for trying! I'm removed the alias as I just had the same idea, and no luck. I've also reduced the query all the way down to select sum(column_2) from myTable and I still don't get results, so feeling my issue is there maybe?

Comment: How many values are there in `column_1`?

Answer (score 0):

Column `trade_price` should be invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Please try below query.

```
SELECT column_1, SUM(column_2) as `trade_price` from [dataset.tableName] group by column_1 order by SUM(column_2) desc limit 10
```

Comment: Oh ok, thank you! But if I want to order the results by the highest sum descending, how would I do that? I'm a little confused because this query works in bigquery console, but not when I put it in my php code?

Comment: @Shenavyre you are most welcome. I have revised my answer to order by  highest sum descending.

Comment: Hi Kazi, thanks for editing your response, this did not work for me either. I think I have worked out that my code is thinking that my numeric data type column is string_literal and this is my problem, but I don't know how or why that's happening! Appreciate your assistance. :)

Comment: It's great to know that you have solved the problem. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this!

```
SELECT column_1, (SELECT SUM(column_2) FROM [dataset.tableName] WHERE Id = tbl.Id) as `trade_price` from [dataset.tableName] tbl group by column_1 order by trade_price desc limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you are working with:

```
SELECT column_1, SUM(column_2) as `trade_price` 
FROM [dataset.tableName] 
GROUP BY column_1 
ORDER BY trade_price desc;
```

You specify that this works okay:

```
SELECT column_1, SUM(column_2) as `trade_price` 
FROM [dataset.tableName] 
GROUP BY column_1 ;
```

The issue is the `ORDER BY` -- and in particular the number of values in `column_1`.  I suspect this is because BigQuery implements `ORDER BY` on a single node; at least, I know this used to be the case.

If you can filter the result to remove much of the data, then that should help performance:  For instance:

```
HAVING SUM(column_2) > 1000
```

or:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
```

I even think the `MAX()` window function can help.  So assuming the largest values are 10% or more of the maximum:

```
SELECT column_1, SUM(column_2) as `trade_price` 
FROM [dataset.tableName] 
GROUP BY column_1 
QUALIFY trade_price >= 0.1 * MAX(trade_price) OVER ()
ORDER BY trade_price desc;
```

Comment: I feel like this sounds like it could be my problem, yet I tried this query and still it didn't return anything, I was so hopeful!
There is about 15 unique values in column one, but there are about 1,050,000 rows of data. There are also nulls for some column_2 results, wondering if that could be my problem?
Close, I'm after the 10 highest sum of column_2.
Thank you for this explanation, I appreciate you breaking it down and trying to help! :)

Comment: @Shenavyre . . . If there are only 15 unique values in `column_1`, then your query should be fine.  I suspect there is some other problem.